# Finding representing matrix to curvature tensor in orthonormal basis

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Let $M^2 \subset\mathbb{R}$ be a regular surface and $ A \in M$.

Assume the gaussian curvature of M at the point A is K
and $e_1, e_2 \in T_AM$ orthonormal basis for the tanget space.

I want to find the representing matrix for the tensor $R(e_1, e_2)$ with respect to the orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2$.

Note: $R: Vec(M)^3 \to Vec(M)$
, given by, $R(X,Y)Z = \nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$
, where X, Y, Z Are vector fields on M, $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection and $[X,Y]$ is the commutator of X and Y.

My initial idea was to look at the embedding of $M^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, by $i :M \to \mathbb{R}^3$.
We have $g_M=i^*(g_{\mathbb{R}^3)}$, so representing $g_M$ in basis $e_1, e_2$ will result in $g_M=I$.
From here, I can easily see that all of the Christoffel ($\Gamma^k_{ij}$) symbols are vanishing at the point A.

If we look at Ricci's curvature $\mathscr{R}_{ij}=R^k_{kij}=\frac{\partial\Gamma_{ij}^k} {\partial q^k} - \frac{\partial\Gamma_{kj}^k} {\partial q^i}$ (I use the notation $\partial q^i=e_i$) and using the fact that $g^{ij }\mathscr{R}_{ij}=\mathscr{K}=2K$ (This is how we formulated theorema egregium in our class)
I ended up with the following equation :

$2K=\frac{\partial\Gamma_{22}^1} {\partial q^1}+\frac{\partial\Gamma_{11}^2} {\partial q^2}-\frac{\partial\Gamma_{21}^2} {\partial q^1}-\frac{\partial\Gamma_{12}^1} {\partial q^2}$

Now
$R(e_1,e_2)_{ij} = \begin{bmatrix}R_{121}^1&R_{121}^2\\R_{122}^1&R_{122}^2\end{bmatrix}$
And generally because the Christoffel coefficients vanishes :
$R_{12k}^l= \frac{\partial\Gamma_{2k}^l} {\partial q^1}-\frac{\partial\Gamma_{1k}^l} {\partial q^2}$.

I hoped that getting to this stage things would start cancelling out, but they don't.

I would appriciate any help completing this question!

Comment: Your question confuses me. Why is the answer not (up to sign) $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & K \\ -K & 0\end{bmatrix}$?  What is your definition of Gaussian curvature? Be warned that you cannot find local coordinates where $\partial/\partial q^i$ is an orthonormal basis locally. At one point, yes. But I still don't understand what all this computation is supposed to be for.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the comment. I can't see why that would be the answer, could you elaborate how you got to that?
My definition to Gaussian curvature is the determinant of $g^{-1}B$ (Where B is the 2nd fundemental form) and I've seen how it relates to the scalar curvature ($\mathscr{K}=2K$).
The computation was in order to find $\frac{\partial \Gamma}{\partial q^i}$, since the representing matrix only include terms of this kind (Since $\Gamma^k_{ij}=0$ at the point A itself).

Comment: Look at the Gauss equations in the classical differential geometry of surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$. See, for example, pp. 59-60 of my undergraduate text, linked in my profile.

Comment: I find it hard to follow the symbols in your book. I can not find where $E, F ,G l, n, m $ are defined.
The formulation of gauss equations I'm familiar with is (using summation notation):  $\frac {\partial e^i} {\partial q_j} = \Gamma^k_{ij}e_k - b_{ij}v}$ where $v=\frac {\partial q^1 \partial q^2} {||partial q^1 x \partial q^2||}$ (\partial q is orthonormal basis to the tangent space locally)

Comment: Could not fix the equation above:
$\frac {\partial e^i} {\partial q_j} = \Gamma^k_{ij}e_k - b_{ij}v$ and $v=\frac {\partial q^1 \times \partial q^2} {||\partial q^1 \times\partial q^2||}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of thinking I will expand Ted's comment a little in case anyone else would need it:

I will use the notation $R(X,Y,Z,W) = <R(X,Y,Z),W>$.

We have $R(X,Y,Y,X) = \frac {B(X,X)B(Y,Y)-B(X,Y)}{|X|^2|Y|^2-<X,Y>^2}$ and for the orthonormal basis $R(e_1,e_2,e_2,e_1)=<R(e_1,e_2)e_2,e_1>=K$, symmetric properties of R we get $<R(e_1,e_2)e_1,e_2>=<-R(e_2,e_1)e_1,e_2>=-K$, and $<R(e_1,e_2)e_2,e_2>=<R(e_1,e_2)e_1,e_1>=<R(e_1,e_1)e_1,e_2>=0$ and therefore

$R=\begin{bmatrix}0&K\\-K&0\end{bmatrix}$